# Rasters changing pixel size and range of values when imported into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have observed that when I import rasters into QGIS their pixel size changes and also, the full range of the raster's value does not appear. For instance, I may have a raster with values ranging from 0 to 2890, and QGIS shows my values to range from 10 to 2850.

Does anyone know why this happens and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of such raster file as well info if you have on-the-fly reprojection activated in QGIS? How did you get the reference that says that the range is 0-2890? Could there be a nodata flag set to 0?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS doesn't change the cell size for rasters did you check if the project coordinate reference system is the same as the layers you might have the "reproject on the fly" option set; right click on the layer and select "set project by layer" projection.

QGIS defaults to range clip of 2% (ie 2-98) of the full range of values. Right click on the layer and select properties you can change this in the layer values/styles menu